# Add PWM control to XL4015

Tags: pwm, esp32, step-down

I am using a circuit based on XL4015 to drive a series of high power leds. After that circuit I have a mosfet to dimmer the led. With this configuration everything woks fine.

Now I want to unify both circuits in one just for simplify wiring. Looking at the XL4015 datasheet I see that is possible to shutdown the output if we inject voltage in the feedback. Many circuits do that to add current control. So the question is, Can I connect a pwm output from an ESP32 to this pin to dimmer the leds and go without the mosfet? Will this circuit work (the PWM part)?

[image: Circuit]

As requested, the original circuit

[image]

Comment: Please show your original full circuit. Almost certainly you will have to low-pass filter the PWM in any case.

Comment: I edit the original post with the original circuit

Comment: The "Typical System Application (TTL shutdown function)" section in the [XL4015 datasheet](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/1811081616_XLSEMI-XL4015E1_C51661.pdf) the voltage the the D3 anode needs to be above 3.3V to cause the converter to shutdown. Since the ESP32 has a recommended VDD of 3.3V and VOH High-level (min) output voltage of ``0.8 × VDD`` an PWM output directly from a ESP32 pin won't have a sufficient level to guarantee the converter will shutdown.

Comment: Also, using the PWM to shutdown the converter is likely to cause relatively slow turn off/on (compared to gating with a MOSFET) of the LED supply as C3 is discharged and then charged as the converter output is shutdown / re-enabled. Not sure how much current your LEDs draw.

Comment: Your original circuit doesn't appear to have a means of limiting the maximum current into your LED load.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The Led part is not part of this question. About the voltage, I can add a 5V input and control it with  an npn from the ESP32. In this scenario, How can I calculate the response time of turn on/off?. The leds load is around 1A